# Allow Label Type Creation only within AdminVOB and Disallow in ClientVOB using Trigger

Tags: clearcase

I want to have a trigger within a Client VOB to disallow creation of any Label Type [mklbtype].
All Label Types must be created within AdminVOB using mklbtype command with -global and -acquire options.
In client VOB only mklabel command will be used to attach the Release Label as defined within AdminVOB. Problem is the Client VOB Trigger for mklbtype gets invoked during mklabel operation in ClientVOB.
How do I solve this issue?
May be there is some CLEARCASE_environment variable is there to check for mklbtype trigger invocation during mklabel command.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to define a pre-op trigger on mklabel, which would check if the lbtype already exists.
If it does not, which means mklbtype would be invoked, it would exit in error, denying the mylabel command.

Comment: mklbtype trigger will block the creation. That will not work. Because Labels in the CleintVOB gets created auto-magically when mklabel command is issued. It's a daisy-chain of mklabel-->mklbtype for ClientVOB.

Comment: @user3806728 it will work since the mklabel trigger will be triggered first. And will prevent any mklbtype.

Comment: X:\Test\Config_Spec_Version\Standard_Formats>cleartool mklabel -c "vob_scrubber
feature added" "CCU_LAYER2_TEST_APP_RELEASE_01.02" .\CCU_Test_Stub_Release_Tag_C
onfig_Spec  
Automatically created label type "CCU_LAYER2_TEST_APP_RELEASE_01.02" from global
 definition in VOB "\AdminTest".  
Created label "CCU_LAYER2_TEST_APP_RELEASE_01.02" on ".\CCU_Test_Stub_Release_Tag_Config_Spec" version "\main\CHECKEDOUT".

Comment: As you can see from the Previous Comment, after I entered mklabel command in ClientVOB, it automatically creates the Label Type from AdminVOB using mklbtype command, which calls the trigger. Remember, if I return from mklabel Trigger, then Label won't be attached.

Comment: Did you put in place the preop mklabel trigger? Because that trigger, as a pre-op, should run *before* mklabel and its automatic mklbtype call.

Comment: Yes, I added mklabel trigger. But remember that mklbtype call has to occur from inside mklabel within ClientVOB in order to perform TYPE COPY from AdminVOB.   I want to avoid mklbtype call directly by END-USER on ClientVOB, but I will have to allow mklbtype call through mklabel for ClientVOB. That is the problem I am trying to solve.   You can see the ClearCase log as attached before for mklabel command. "Automatically created label type...." above.

Comment: @user3806728 again: it is a *preop* trigger: it will run *before* the mklabel runs. And it will prevent the mklabel to run because it will detect the label does not exist yet.